# Adding bottom border to dates in formula

Tags: excel-formula, dayofweek

I am looking to have a formula automate some bottom boarders.

The scenario is that I have a schedule that creates weeks which is already formula driven to continue down but wish to automate the month changes where the majority of a week lies in the previous month.

So if one starts on 12th feb the 19th would be the ending week due to the 26/2/18 having the majority of a week falling in March.

Does this need to be macro driven as I'm not too sharp on those.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Shaun

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code.

Comment: I haven't tried anything as of yet but I have just been looking into threads to see if it had been raised previously.

Comment: Take a look at something called conditional formatting

Comment: I have thought about conditional formatting but what formula would be needed? Cell value between (month-4)  and (month +3)

Answer (score 0):

With data as shown, where shown, I applied the red lines with a Conditional Formatting formula rule of:

```
=EOMONTH(A1,0)-A1<3
```

Applied to ColumnA.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that has worked in some instances but not in all as you can see from your screengrab the 26/03/17 would have a line appearing under it. I tried extending the day count to see if that would help but still hasnt quite managed it. I think it would need further rulings added in. I have currently used =EOMONTH(A2,0)-A2<7 which covers about 70% of instances but unfortunately still not entirely usable